# Installing Windows-based software on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I want to install Windows-based software on Ubuntu 18.04, specifically Wordsearch Basic, Bible study software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Wordsearch using playonlinux app. It lets you install some windows software on ubuntu and other linux distros but according to test result of this particular software https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=4568 . i guess it wont work.

You can try installing alternative softwares for example

"The CrossWire Bible" which is available for linux and is open source.

"E-Sword is working using playonlinux or wine".